# android XWalkView content width

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, crosswalk

How to set content width == device-width?
HTML code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,  initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

div for page rendering

```
  <style>
    body {
    background-color: #808080;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    }
 </style>
 <div id="pageContainer" class="pdfViewer singlePageView"></div>
```

style css for div

```
.textLayer > div {
 color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: pre;
 margin: 0 auto;
cursor: text;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

initial scale == 1.0, but really scale more then device with...

Answer (score -1):

@Illya Bublyk Which Crosswalk version you are using? Please try the [latest version](https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/canary/latest/).

I have compared to WebView, the page display is a little smaller than XWalkView, do you mean this?

It's better to file a new issue in our Jira: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK and supply the sample.

With WebView, the page could not be scaled even if `user-scalable=yes` was specified.

@bitoiu I have no enough reputations to add comment, so I have to add answer here to discuss.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12564426)

Comment: I have no enough reputations to add comment, so I have to add answer here to discuss.

Comment: I'm sorry chmsky, but that's just how the website is able to scale and keep some sort of order. While you don't have enough reputation, you need to refrain from adding comments as answers. Soon enough you'll reach the amount of rep needed.